# React Native - Unable to get params that have been passed through navigator(from stack navigator to drawer navigator). Recieving: Object is undefined

Tags: android, react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

The params have been passed and I can see them in the logs but I cannot access them. Screen one is the login screen and is within the stack navigator and screen two is the profile screen which is within the drawer navigator.

**Within screen one:**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileRoute', {name: data.name});
```

The line above works and the correct data is picked to be passed. The params are successfully passed, I can see this within the logs.

**Within screen two:**

There are various ways which I have tried to "catch" or "call" the params passed.

1.

```
<Text style={styles.name}>{this.props.navigation.params.name}</Text>
```

2.

```
<Text style={styles.name}>{this.props.navigation.state.params.name}</Text>
```

3.

```
 <Text style={styles.name}>{this.naviation.params.name}</Text>
```

---

I have looked it up and the 1st way seems to be the most recommended but I still receive the undefined object error directed to the first part of the line `this.props.navigation.params`

I have read that the undefined object error occurs when the parameter being requested for has no value. However I can see within the logs that this param has a value.

Is there a specific way one passes data and calls params between the two different kinds of navigators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end....

**Inside the previous page/screen**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenOneRoute', {name: data.name});
```

**Inside the next screen**

```
var {params} = this.props.navigation.state; 
let name = params.name;
```

*inside the return*

```
<Text>{name}</Text>
```

Note: data is what I call the information I get from a response from my db